# Simple code not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

This is not working in google chrome. Any idea why?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="css/text">
      #wrapper{display:none}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper" >
      This is a test this is a test
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean in other browsers this code works?Weird...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`css/text` should be `text/css`.

```
<style type="text/css">
```

In HTML5, however, a `style` element's `type` will default to "text/css" if it isn't specified, so depending on which browsers you're supporting you could drop it altogether.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I was editing the answer when you edited your comment. Just had to check the specification first to make sure I wasn't making that up! :)

Comment: Aay ayy confirmed, it's completely valid :)

Answer (score 0):

Style tag should be:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

Or even better, remove it!

```
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change

`<style type="css/text">` to `<style type="text/css">`

Answer (score 0):

it's `text/css` not the other way around. :P

Answer (score 0):

remove this attribute:

```
type="css/text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper{display:none}
        </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" >
        This is a test this is a test
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Gosh, so many duplicates, do you guys read the upvoted answer? Or did you provide anything different from other answers?